Bad version of the SoLoader SDK - version 0.10.4 or higher - Google Play Console Issue
Play Console
Recently tried uploading the app on play console and confront with the red issue saying BAD version of the SoLoader SDK. Check below:

React Native
Checked in android/app/build.gradle founded version was 0.9.0 which I then updated like below:
implementation ('com.facebook.soloader:soloader:0.10.4')
I checked dependency tree ./gradlew app:dependencies. Looked fine.
Check below:

Tried again uploading and faced the same red issue warning by Google Play.
To figure out on which part of the bundle google has put check on. Any ideas would be helpful.

were you able to fix this ?

reported what was happening using the options available and this never occurred again
